# How do I add the elements of this vector together?

Tags: c++, vector, cout

The purpose of my code is to add the elements of a vector together into one integer.  This is for Problem #1 on Project Euler:

https://projecteuler.net/problem=1

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
  int max_count = 1000; //The upper bound

  //Loop for filling vector
  for (int i = 1; i <= max_count; ++i){
      int counter[max_count];

      if (counter[i] % 3 == 0|| counter[i] % 5 == 0){
          vector <int> start_point = {};
          start_point.push_back (counter[i]);
            for (auto& n : start_point){
                int sum_of_elems = 0;
                sum_of_elems += n;
                cout << sum_of_elems;
            }   

      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Currently, my code is outputting the following and I cannot figure out why.

```
32766143547943202305202750000-4646761603276630-76434810000-76434582500-464677056327662448-4646770403276632766-46467703232766327666032766230586999-970904238-95777621723084852023084852032766-970904244-46467688032766230624075-970911300230826120-1916976912327663276623063434032766230634681-957776214230826120140084992032766-970911280327660003276603276630-4646761603276623058081332766-464676440327663276632766230831712230745153065793306031200003276623074515300-191647711200023084852023074515365793360036000002308224802307451533657937207200-46467616032766000023083171232766230595552230831712032766327660-46467619232766230577342230822480230829920000-46467616032766230822480230829960-46467264032766230540223001920409600-46467247232766327661920409600-46467220832766000000000011072962560230556921230818160-4646738403276619204096000000230510592-1572142422000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001920169263100000170147416279176918919693827240000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Reading the problem, I have no idea why you're using an array *or* a vector at all. This is a summation problem. Start with a sum of 8. Then, loop from 6 through (but not including) 1000, testing each number to see if it is a multiple of 3 or 5 (and note, it may be both). If it is, add its value to the sum. When the loop is done your answer should be 233168. If it isn't, you made a mistake somewhere. [No arrays nor vectors are required for this *at all*.](https://ideone.com/kKv0eI)

Comment: `int counter[max_count];` -- This is not legal C++.  Why didn't you use `std::vector<int> counter(max_count);` here?

Comment: I appreciate the help guys, as I did end up getting the program to work as intended. I think the problem is that I was overthinking this problem waaaaay too much. I'm new to this, so this is all good stuff, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're reinitializing your `sum` variable on each loop, so you end up just printing the individual values. You're also mixing looping and summing, which is complicating your code; either skip the `vector` entirely (just have a summing loop), or fill it completely, then sum it.

I can't give much more useful advice because you've got a lot of associated problems here. You declare `counter` without initializing it, then read from uninitialized memory to populate `start_point`.

Point is, most of your variables need to be declared outside the loops (so they're not repeatedly reinitialized from scratch on *each* loop), your output should be after the loops, and `counter` needs real data so you're not invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Removing vectors and other unnecessary variables, the code can be simplified to:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int max_count = 1000; //The upper bound
  int sumOfMultiples = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < max_count; ++i)
      if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        sumOfMultiples = sumOfMultiples + i;

   std::cout << "Sum of  Multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000 is: " << sumOfMultiples << "\n";      

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Sum of  Multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000 is: 233168
```